# Dividing Scrolling text

Tags: macros, positioning

Based on the video available here :  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkBCeOBbAmM 
I try to understand what the following code does

```
\def\text{\setbox\galley=\vbox\bgroup
\hsize= 5cm
\hrule}

\makeatletter
\def\endtext{\vskip-\prevdepth
\vfil\egroup
\setbox0=\vsplit\galley to\z@}
\makeatother

\def\lines#1{\vsplit\galley
to #1\baselineskip}
```

unfortunately, I am not sucessful. In the video, he speaks about "floating, scrolling text" which you can cut in pieces and place the different pieces in the page. But I fail to understand how to do that with the previous code lines. I begin in macro writing so it could be I do not understand because I do not undestand the effect of the different commands put under these macros.

I tried

```
\text blablablabla \endtext
```

to check the effect but the page does not display any text at all then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
\input plipsum

\newbox\galley
\def\text{\setbox\galley=\vbox\bgroup
  \hsize=10cm \hrule height 0pt}

\catcode`\@=11
\def\endtext{\vskip-\prevdepth
  \vfil\egroup
  \setbox0=\vsplit\galley to \z@}
\catcode`\@=12

\def\lines#1{\vsplit\galley to #1\baselineskip}

\text
\lipsum 1,3
\endtext

\noindent{\bf Four lines:}\par\medskip

\setbox0=\lines{4}\box0

\bigskip

\noindent{\bf Five lines:}\par\medskip

\setbox0=\lines{5}\box0

\bye
```

The big text has much more than nine lines. We gather it in a `\vbox`, then chop off the initial (invisible) rule. With `\lines{`*x*`}` we can chop *x* lines from the top of the paragraph and set them in a box which we can do anything with. In the example we just print it.

[image]